# Angular - Azure Key Vault Managing Vault Access secrets

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault, azure-ad-msal

Is it possible to use Azure Key Vault to get a vault access secret in an Angular app?

I am working with Azure Active Directory using implicit flow, which means that I am implementing everything without a back-end. In my Angular project, I am using Microsoft Authentication Library (Angular MSAL) to acquire tokens from Microsoft Identity Platform endpoint to access secure web APIs. Now, I want to use Azure Key Vault as a tool to safely store and access secrets. I plan to use it to protect client-id, b2c-policy-name, b2c-scope.

I have not found any information on the possibility of implementing logic on the frontend side to manage Azure Key Vault. At the same time, I created a Node JS server project using ENV to manage Azure Key Vault and it works successfully, but I want to get the same in my Angular app.

```
export const msalConfig: Configuration = {
    auth: {
        clientId: MY_CLIENT_ID, // I want to use Key Vault here
        authority: b2cPolicies.authorities.signUpSignIn.authority,
        redirectUri: 'http://localhost:6420/',
        postLogoutRedirectUri: 'http://localhost:6420/',
        navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true,
        validateAuthority: false,
      },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
        storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE,
    },
};
```

Comment: Hi - have to got any solution for this? I have also the same ask here. If you found any please do share

Answer (score 3):

this is not possible. also, is not recommended even if it were possible. 
if you could connect to key vault to retrieve secrets in javascript on client side, it's a huge security risk, as anyone could be able to access your secrets. it does not provide any security.

as best practice you should never access secured resources directly from client code.

Hope that helps, 
Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You can write an Azure function to encapsulate the key vault. An azure function can be a managed identity and can access the key vault. The function itself can be secured by Azure Active Directory so that only your registered users can trigger the function.
Your Angular app can then call the Azure function to get the secret.

Regards

[Access key vault from Azure function](https://www.markheath.net/post/managed-identity-key-vault-azure-functions#:%7E:text=Accessing%20Key%20Vault%20from%20Azure%20Functions%20using%20Managed,secrets%206%20Accessing%20the%20secrets%20in%20Azure%20Functions)

[Secure Azure function with AAD](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/secure-azure-function-with-azure-ad/)