# Windows VM system-assigned managed identity to access Azure Key Vault in Typescript?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-keyvault

How we can get the Access to Azure key vault secrets from Typescript app.
We have access to the VM on which the application is running.
What are the steps and code we need to place in **Type script react application to get azure key vault access**?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible and not recommended to use Azure key vault in Typescript app. It is a security risk, as anyone can see your KeyVault connection details from browser console and access your secrets.

You should not access secured resources directly from client code.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/keyvault-secrets

[Angular - Azure Key Vault Managing Vault Access secrets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61741877/angular-azure-key-vault-managing-vault-access-secrets)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/318983/is-it-possible-to-use-key-vault-in-static-web-appl.html